# How to migrate to drupal from dolphin (boonex)

Tags: drupal, migration, boonex-dolphin

How to migrate to drupal from dolphin (boonex).

I have a 2 dolphin sites and i like to move to drupal can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to build a new site on Drupal and then you might be able to migrate some of the content. Migration can either be done by hand (recommended in most cases) or programmatically, with the help of https://drupal.org/project/migrate for example.

Comment: Yes, I know my question is if someone can help me, I know that there is this mode but that does not help, I do not know how to use it

Comment: You would have to try to use it and if encounter a problem you cannot solve then you should ask a new question where you describe what you did, what you want to achieve and what's the exact problem. Otherwise it's impossible to help you.

Comment: Tanks #laurik Today I will try to see how it works, and if I have a problem i announcement. regards